# JSData: Sometimes resources are accessed nested under parent resource, and other times not. How is this determined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsdata, js-data-angular

I am integrating with an api that exposes child resources nested under parent resources.

This seems to work fine when I am finding or creating resources from JSData, however, updates and deletes seem to want to access the resource directly.

```
GET & POST:
/api/parents/:parent_id/children
```

But, with delete and put requests:

```
DELETE & PUT
/api/children/:child_id
```

It seems like if there is a object id involved for the child record then the url that is constructed is constructed at the base level of the API, and if there is no object id, as is the case with POST and GET (findAll).

Is there something very obvious that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a bit more about relations in JS-Data here: 
http://www.js-data.io/docs/relations

I saw this part,

```
    // if you add this to a belongsTo relation
    // then js-data will attempt to use
    // a nested url structure, e.g. /organization/15/user/4
    parent: true
```

under the "Defining Relations" header. I had two relations with the 
`parent: true` configuration which I think confused JS-Data's router.